# Image view between two layout

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have to set round image view between two layout which is marked from red line in image below

[image]

I am achieving this UI using `weight` so that i can use it in any device but the problem is that i am not able to put that imageview between two layout. Any suggestions will be great help.

Comment: I think if you will use relative layout then also it should work in all devices.

Comment: @Bharat Sharma but i dont want to set hard coded margin for that imageview. So how to achieve that??

Comment: If you don't want to add hard coded margin, I think you should divide your image in two, right in the middle, and then add them with alignBottom/top on the right layout.

Comment: it's not possible i have to set profile pic in that imageview. It will look weird

Answer (score 1):

This can be acheived using a frameLayout:

> **This layout makes it very easy to draw on top of other layouts.** 
>   https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Constructing-View-Layouts

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to occupy the space in between the 2 layouts take `LinearLayout` as root layout with `android:orientation="vertical"` and keep the image between the 2 layouts with `android:layout_height="0dp"` and`android:layout_weight="1"`. The image will occupy whatever space is left between the 2 layout at run time.

Comment: it will generate black space behind `ImageView`

Comment: Take a `LinearLayout` as `Imageview` parent with `android:layout_height="0dp"`,`android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`. This will give a transparent background and place the `ImageView` in the center of the `LinearLayout`